# Question on a sum of independent normal variables

Tags: probability

The weight of luggage that aircraft passengers take with them is normally distributed, with mean 20 kg and st. dev. 5kg. An aircraft carries 100 passengers. What is the approximate probability that the total weight of the passengers' luggage exceeds 2.150 kg?

So I let $X_i, 1 ≤ i ≤ 100$ be the weight of each passenger's luggage (obviously all independent from one another). Then $S = ΣX_i$ is normally distributed, with mean $20*100 = 2000$ kg and variance $25*100 = 2500$ kg (so st.dev. = $50$ kg). Then  I get $P(S ≥ 2150) = P(z ≥ 3)$, where $z$ is the standard normal variable. Is this correct? I feel like I might have messed up the st.dev. and variance somewhere in my calculation.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: correct provided $2.150=2150$.